# SystemVerilog Array Index

Tags: system-verilog

i have a module like this:

```
module ArrayTest(input logic clk, [9:0] sindex, output shortint OBYTE);
shortint ima_step_table[89] = { 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 
    19, 21, 23, 25, 28, 31, 34, 37, 41, 45, 
    50, 55, 60, 66, 73, 80, 88, 97, 107, 118, 
    130, 143, 157, 173, 190, 209, 230, 253, 279, 307,
    337, 371, 408, 449, 494, 544, 598, 658, 724, 796,
    876, 963, 1060, 1166, 1282, 1411, 1552, 1707, 1878, 2066, 
    2272, 2499, 2749, 3024, 3327, 3660, 4026, 4428, 4871, 5358,
    5894, 6484, 7132, 7845, 8630, 9493, 10442, 11487, 12635, 13899, 
    15289, 16818, 18500, 20350, 22385, 24623, 27086, 29794, 32767 
};
initial begin
    OBYTE <= -1;
end

always@ (posedge clk) begin
    OBYTE = ima_step_table[sindex];
end
endmodule
```

I am using Digilent Basys3 board and `clk` is its clock. `sindex` is switches on fpga and it shows output `OBYTE` with leds. Problem is it does not show the correct value. It shows 7, the first value, when `sindex` is between 88-95 or 120-127, meaning when `sindex[6]`, `[4]`, `[3]` are 1. For any other `sindex` value it shows 0. I have no idea why this is happening.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Putting array initialization in initial has worked but I still appreciate if someone explains the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think how you model and initialize an array as a loop-up table depends on the level of SystemVerilog support from your synthesis tool. In SystemVerilog, I would have at declared `ima_step_table` as a `parameter` or `const` to indicate that it is never to be written to. But many synthesis tools still only support Verilog-1995 syntax which only gives you the choice of an `initial` block to initialize an array. Verilog-2001 added variable declaration initializations, but not for arrays. SystemVerilog added array literals and the ability to declare an array as a `parameter` or `const`